# tls_process_server_certificate in python request module

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

When I put the request form request module in python, I am facing following issue.

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats the version of request package? In some cases, downgrading to 2.11.1 works.
If you are in test mode, you can try to put in the request get "verify=False", you'll get a warning but it should work.

Comment: It is better to place this answer as a comment.

Comment: Can´t, not enough reputation. Just trying to help though, but I can delete this.